# How can I make my userid point to /user/*/ instead of pointing to /user/*/home?

Tags: path-aliases

Currently if I set my pathauto pattern to:
u/[user:account-name]

The result I receive is:
Alias: /u/michelleclark System Path: /user/5/home

I would like to recieve the result of:
Alias: /u/michelleclark System Path: /user/5/

Is there a way I can make it stop adding home on the end of the system path?

I am using a pre-made drupal distribution. I did ask in their issues section. I am not expecting a response anytime soon.

[edit]
I am using the open social distribution: https://www.drupal.org/project/social

Specifically the pre-built template from their github:
https://github.com/goalgorilla/social_template/

[edit] - added an image to show what I mean exactly.
[image: pattern issues]

Comment: Who's `their` and what distribution? Update your question.

Comment: @leymannx I have updated my post with the requested information.

Comment: What happens when you visit /user/5? Does it still work? Maybe it's just the default tab built with Views, you can ignore the last path fragment of the default tab path.

Comment: @prkos it still sends me to a profile typing in /user/5. The problem is that when trying to setup a url alias with a pattern. I want to make it so the users login name or nickname shows on their profile url instead of user/5. The pattern points to user/5/home by default when creating a url alias.

Comment: What are all the aliases you have for the user path?

Comment: @prkos I have added an image to the post. Maybe it will be clearer if I show you what I mean. I am new to using Drupal. I am wondering if the "user" pattern type needs to be edited? I have checked my views and there is no view that points to /user/*/home from what I see.

Comment: I don't see it as an automatic problem at all. It seems that you have the /home added somewhere in your configuration. You say it's not in any Views. I can't think where else you could check where it originates. Have you checked all Page Displays within Views?

Comment: @prkos I am continuing to look everywhere. The user has an information page attached. The information page path is: Path:/user/%user/information which results in http://websitename.com/user/1/information. None of the user account urls point to /home. Even going to user/5/home redirects you to the user/5/information or /user/5/stream if you change it in your account settings to stream as your default user page. 

I am really confused as to why /home is being used as the system path. When /home is not in any of the urls on the users page.

Comment: I meant to say "automatic path pattern" problem. What you describe with user/5/home redirecting too user/5 sounds exactly like the default Menu tab in Views behaviour. Search for answers on Drupal tabs in Views to see how they're done and check your Information and Stream Views for their Menu settings, see how the Default tab is set. If it's not that it may be something specific about the distribution you're using, check their documentation.